# Mobile browsers force content-box?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive

I design responsive web page with box-sizing: border-box.
In desktop browsers web inspectors mobile view, all the boxed/padded elements fit perfectly.

But when I switch to real mobile device (Android with Chrome and built-in browser), box-sizing seem forced to content-box and I get horrible horizontal scrolling, roughly the same size margins and paddings would add if there was content-box on.

I tried some different css like

```
* {box-sizing: border-box} 
html {box-sizing: border-box} * {box-sizing: inherit}
every, single, boxed, element {box-sizing: border-box}
```

Nothing works.

This code `every, single, boxed, element {width: 90%}` comes to remove horizontal scrolling, so there's no hidden element wider than screen width.

Why would mobile browsers force content-box? Have any clues and worked fixes?

Comment: Please post your html so we can help

Comment: https://diagnos.ru/diseases/cutis/acne

Comment: Your website is working great for me. Using iPhone SE. tried it on chrome and safari. Don’t see any issues.

Comment: Thanks! At least, we see that this is an android problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set a margin: 0 to the body?
If you use a wrapper around your html with horizontal margin auto, I think you'll be rid of the horizontal scrollbar and the resize/zoom of the browser will be more snoothly.

```
<body>
  <div class="page">
    <!-- your html here -->
  </div>
</body>


html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.page {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Yes, of course I tried this. 
Perhaps there's a 3d party script forcing css to change.

Comment: OK, perhaps that may cause the change in box-sizing. When using a minimal html/css it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to screen-related units worked fine!
Mobile browsers never let themselves ignore such type of units, so if we switch from percents to viewWidth, horizontal scrolling never appears.

The solution:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {max-width: 100vw}
}
```